# unity NullReferenceException on object call

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I am new to this, so please bear with me. I am trying to create a line-of-sight effect by hiding from the camera tiles and entities not touched by the array of `linecast` sent out by the players character. I am getting a `NullReferenceException` that seems to be telling me 'hit' is not set to an object, which while true (it's a RaycastHit variable, to my knowledge), the line of code the error points to is supposed to run off the `gameObject` of the thing hit by 'hit'. The line in question is below:

```
hit.transform.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Visible");
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
public class LoS : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Vector3 direction;
    private Vector3 rot1;
    private Vector3 rot2;
    private int d;
    private int r;
    private Ray ray;
    private GameObject hit;

    public Rigidbody point;

    void Start () 
    {
        direction = new Vector3(135, 0, 0);
        rot2 = new Vector3(0, 6, 0);
        rot1 = new Vector3(15, 0, 0);
    }

    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        d = 0;
        r = 0;
        while (d <= 360) 
        {
            d += 1;
            Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, direction);
            RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
            Physics.Linecast(transform.position, direction, out hit);
            hit.transform.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Visible");
            if (r <= 60) 
            {
                direction += rot2;
                r += 1;
                if (r == 60) 
                {
                    direction += rot1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Always use cast with if condition: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Linecast.html

Comment: Check if the object is not null `if(hit != null)`  before the `hit.transform....`